# PHP grouping content of multidimensional array with new structure

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I usually use Eloquent so transposing the data is much easier. However i'm struggling to this in vanilla PHP.

I have tried `array_map(null, ...$array)` however get an error due to it not being an array.

I have got the following keyed array:

```
[
    'email' => [
        "william.pool@gmail.com",
        "martynleeball@gmail.com"
    ],
    'lastName' => [
        'Pool',
        'Ball'
    ],
    'firstName' => [
        'William',
        'Martyn'
    ],
    'id' => [
        'j8zwyk',
        '1'
    ]
]
```

I need to convert this to the following format:

```
[
    0 => [
        'email' => "william.pool@gmail.com",
        'lastName' => 'Pool',
        'firstName' => 'William',
        'id' => 'j8zwyk'
    ],
    1 => [
        'email' => "martynleeball@gmail.com",
        'lastName' => 'Ball',
        'firstName' => 'Martyn',
        'id' => '1'
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($value); $i++) {
        $newArray[$i][$key] = $value[$i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Create new array with length 2 and loop through origin array. In loop insert relevant item into new array.

So if your array has only 2 item per key use

```
$newArr = [];
foreach($arr as $key=>$item){
    $newArr[0][$key] = $item[0];
    $newArr[1][$key] = $item[1];   
}
```

But if it has unknown item use

```
$newArr = [];
foreach($arr as $key=>$item){
    foreach($item as $key2=>$item2)
        $newArr[$key2][$key] = $item2;
}
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/ri7Kr)

Comment: Close, but that doesn't account for if I get more than 2 emails etc... this is basically a form submitting, so the amount of emails and names etc could be any.

Comment: Spot on, thanks. I did think of doing it like this but I figured there might be a better way.

Comment: Second example is the best way, better than my answer, because it doesn't assume all child arrays have the same count.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will mark that one as the answer then for historical reference.